# Compare two text files and return the difference (case insensitive)

Tags: python

I'm new to Python programming so forgive me if my code is not efficient, etc. I need to compare text file B with text file B and print the results out to another file. Simply put, result C = text file A - text file B.

I have the following code which works, however, there are duplicate results due to upper and lower cases. How can I make it such that my program can compare it without case sensitivity?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python -u

file1='A_GAGL.txt'
file2='B_GGL.txt'

def key(line):
  return tuple(line.strip().split()[0:2])

def make_key_set(file_path):
  return set(key(line) for line in open(file_path))


def filtered_lines(file_path1, file_path2):
  key_set = make_key_set(file_path2)
  return (line for line in open(file_path1) if key(line) not in key_set)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  file3 = open("file4.txt", "w")
  for line in filtered_lines(file1, file2):
      file3.write(line)
  file3.close()
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: The indentation is all messed up (and that's important in Python)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `make_key_set`, convert everything to lowercase:

```
return set(key(line.lower()) for line in open(file_path)
```

Then in `filtered_lines` check whether the lowercase line is in `key_set` (but return the original-case line):

```
return (line for line in open(file_path1) if key(line.lower()) not in key_set)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make your keys uppercase:

```
def key(line):
    return map(str.upper, line.strip().split()[0:2])
```

---

Also, instead of `file3 = open("file4.txt", "w")` and `file3.close()`, 
if you Python version is 2.5 or newer, the better way is to use a [`with` context manager](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm):

```
with open("file4.txt", "w") as file3:
    for line in filtered_lines(file1, file2):
        file3.write(line)
```

This guarantees the file is closed no matter how it exits the with-block, and it ensures you never forget to call `close()`.

Answer (score 1):

if your files are line-oriented plain text, then:

```
 class HashableDictWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.original_str = s
        self._hash_key = hash(s.strip()[0:2].lower())

    def __hash__(self):
        return self._hash_key

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__hash__()==other.__hash__()

 if __name__=="__main__":
    a = map(HashableDictWrapper, open("A.txt"))
    b = map(HashableDictWrapper, open("B.txt"))
    result = map(lambda x:x.original_str, set(a) - set(b))
    open("C.txt", "w").writelines(result)
```